# c++ int member changes on its own

Tags: c++, class, member

I am new to c++. 
It looks like member variable `_scheduleSize` gets value kind of "integer_half_max" without any reason. Could someone please explain me why is this happening?

Invocation

```
   leds.addSchedulePoint(new ScheduledLedPoint(ScheduleTime(9), 0));
```

of method:

```
void ScheduledLeds::addSchedulePoint(ScheduledLedPoint *schedulePoint) {
  Serial.print("_scheduleSize:");
  Serial.println(_scheduleSize);

  _schedule[_scheduleSize++] = schedulePoint;

  Serial.print("_scheduleSize:");
  Serial.println(_scheduleSize);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < _scheduleSize; i++) {
    Serial.println(_schedule[i]->getLevel());
  }
}
```

results in such console output :

```
_scheduleSize:0
_scheduleSize:1073680860
0

Exception (28):
epc1=0x40206514 epc2=0x00000000 epc3=0x00000000 excvaddr=0x00000010 depc=0x00000000
```

Below you can see entire class:

```
class ScheduledLeds {
    public:
        ScheduledLeds(int pin);
        void addSchedulePoint(ScheduledLedPoint *schedulePoint);
        void process(ScheduleTime currentTime);
        void freezeLedLevel(int targetLevel, int minutes);
        int _pin;
    private:
        ScheduledLedPoint *_schedule[];
        int _scheduleSize;
        int _count;
        int _size;
        long _unfreezeTime;
        int _lastLevel;
        ScheduleTime _lastTime;
        void setTransitionalLightLevel(ScheduleTime now, ScheduledLedPoint nextPoint);
        void setLightLevel(int targetLevel);
};

ScheduledLeds::ScheduledLeds(int pin) {
  pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
  _pin = pin;
  _scheduleSize = 0;
  _size = 10;
  _unfreezeTime = millis();
  ScheduledLedPoint *_schedule[_size];
}

void ScheduledLeds::addSchedulePoint(ScheduledLedPoint *schedulePoint) {
  Serial.print("_scheduleSize:");
  Serial.println(_scheduleSize);

  _schedule[_scheduleSize++] = schedulePoint;

  Serial.print("_scheduleSize:");
  Serial.println(_scheduleSize);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < _scheduleSize; i++) {
    Serial.println(_schedule[i]->getLevel());
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome. When posting a question about why something doesn't work you should always include an [MCVE] - the process of producing this will often help you to solve the problem yourself, but if it doesn't you are welcome to post it here.

Comment: You should avoid `new`, use smart pointer instead.

Comment: related: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: `ScheduledLedPoint *_schedule[_size];` is a local variable. Use `std::vector`.

Comment: This code is intended to work on arduino, so std::vector is not the case here.

Comment: I recommend not using dynamic memory in embedded systems.  You may end up with fragmented memory and not able to reclaim large amounts of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ScheduledLedPoint *_schedule[];` is not valid C++ and shouldn't compile. Some compilers accept it as an extension - but even there, it's an array of zero size; `_schedule[x]` exhibits undefined behavior for any value of `x`.

When you write `ScheduledLedPoint *_schedule[_size]` in the constructor, that doesn't affect the data member named `_schedule`, as you seem to believe. Instead, it creates and immediately destroys a local variable that also happens to be named `_schedule`; this has exactly zero net effect.

For an array-like data structure of variable size, use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: This code is intended to work on arduino, so std::vector is not the case here. Still can't understand why `_scheduleSize` gets value of 1.07 billion?

Comment: You are writing past the end of the array. `_scheduleSize` just happens to be located in memory right after the array, and gets clobbered with random garbage. In effect, you are doing `_scheduleSize = reinterpret_cast<int>(schedulePoint)`

Answer (score -1):

because you have syntax error including this recursive function